# Rails 3.2 has_one with conditions always places foreign_key into where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a has_one relationship setup with conditions => proc {["test_column = 10"]} and it always puts primary_key = 1 in with the conditional statement giving me incorrect results. How can I create a has_one relationship with a custom set of conditions that will not have the current models key in it?

```
has_many testers,
  :class_name => "testers",
  :conditions => proc {["test_column = 10"]}
```

I am using Rails 3.2.12

Comment: why not just `:conditions => ["test_column=10"]` ?

Comment: The value is actually dynamic. But I did try that also and it still has model.primary_key = key inside the query. It's very odd behavior.

Comment: ok - honestly, it's hard to see what's going on without more code

Comment: Okay if you have an example of how to do a has_one relationship with a conditions statement that may also help.

Comment: normally, I do something like a User has_one :profile so I'm not sure where the condition comes in. I was figuring you're trying to do like a composite where the user_id AND the test_column are the foreign key but can have multiple testers with test_column being different. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: No I don't want to include the primary_key = ? And as part of the statement. It's doing a lookup on that table for a child record but it's tied through another relationship. It's a very tricky query to say the least.

Comment: do you mean foreign key? I think you want a scope http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes because how could you have a belongs to in that structure?

Comment: We actually solved this a different way. Instead of trying to make it all happen in one has_one condition we separated it out into multiple has_one's and then chained them to get the end result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the condition in the the has_one association, please find the below code.

```
has_one tester, :conditions => "testers.test_column = 10"
```

You can refer to 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Note - in later rails versions they took away the very helpful "conditions" option, so you can't do this any more.  You can use "where" with their arrow-curly-brace syntax - but that works differently, in many cases.